# закрыть прямой доступ к странице, но оставить возможность для ajax подгружать эту страницу на сайт

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

Пример, есть страница index.php на нее подгружаем с помощью ajax некий контент со страницы content.php

Но если вести в адресную строку просто мой сайт.com/content.php контент тоже показывается.

Как сделать чтоб с index.php контент был виден, А напрямую по ссылке сайт.com/content.php нет?

Возможно заблокировать с помощью htaccess ? если просто заблокировать там content.php то он и в ajax не подгрузится

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К примеру так

```
function isAjaxRequest()
{
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
        return false;
    }
    return 'XMLHttpRequest' === $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'];
}
```

соответвенно

```
if (!isAjaxRequest())
{
    exit(); //Ну или ваша реализаци
}
```

Comment: не знал про $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']

благодарю